# Adding a scrollable textPad in python tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a complete GUI created with python tkinter and its working fine. I would like to convert this "Notes" textvariable to a scrollable textPad/textWidget to save more info. while having greater visibility in the GUI. Could anyone please guide me or share a link to apply it here. I have tried the columnspan and rowspan options in Entry but the whole box is moving instead of a merge. Please provide some suggestions.

[image: GUI-Image]

Comment: Use the `Text` widget instead of `Entry` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I figured it out. Its a scrolledtext widget. I am not a GUI programmer but enjoying this very much.

```py
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(f1, width=30, height=3, wrap=tk.WORD)
scr.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky='WE', columnspan=3
```